# How to ungroup popup window from the application on the taskbar?

Tags: windows, taskbar

Is it possible to instruct the shell taskbar to exclude a certain `hwnd` popup window from the main application's button "group"?

I have a *"stopwatch"* popup window. On my machine, with taskbar button combining disabled, the windows appears exactly as i'd like it: a separate item on the taskbar:

[image]

But if the user uses (the default, and most corporations prevent users from altering their personal preferences), the separate window is not visible:

[image]

Now, i *am* using [`ITaskbarList3.SetOverlayIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391696%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to specify an overlay icon for my popup window:

```
list: ITaskbarList3;

list := CoTaskbarList3.Create;
list.SetOverlayIcon(windowHandle, ico, '');
```

so Windows will at least do me the favour of picking the most recent overlay icon, and applying it to the combined visual group - which is nice.

But i'd still prefer to have this separate action in a separate item on the taskbar.

One horrible workaround would be to ship another executable with my application; one just to fool the grouper into putting this other hwnd in its own group. But that's not something i want to do.

### Why would i think i'm allowed to do this?

I was surprised to learn that you are allowed to [prevent the user from pinning an application to the taskbar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/01/10170113.aspx).

And while [the MSDN page on shell programming doesn't give an example specifically for what i want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that doesn't mean it's not out there. It just might mean that it's all poorly documented.

Comment: You can use application IDs to [customize how your windows are grouped by the taskbar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/17/10340743.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you, sir. I remember that blog entry; but didn't realize it could control grouping. I thought it was simply an identifier associated to a window, in order to customize jump lists and recent documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the *"operator"* has a stopwatch. When they start the stopwatch, i pop out the form of the application group by giving it a different **User Model Application ID**:

```
SetWindowAppModelUserID('Contoso.Frobber.Stopwatch');
```

and immediately the form pops out:

[image]

When the user stops (or pauses) the stopwatch, i let the window coalesce back into the application:

```
SetWindowAppModelUserID('');
```

[image]

## Caveats

You don't actually set the **AppModelUserID** to an empty string; that is not a valid application identifer. Instead you set it to `VT_EMPTY`. My helpful wrapper function checks for `''`, and converts it into a `VT_EMPTY` value.

Another [warning comes from the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378430.aspx):

> A window's properties must be removed before the window is closed. If this is not done, the resources used by those properties are not returned to the system. A property is removed by setting it to the [PROPVARIANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) type VT_EMPTY.

This means that care needs to be taken to remove a custom property applied to an `HWND` before i destroy it. A somewhat daunting task; one that i will almost certainly screw up.

## The Code

```
function TFormEx.SetWindowAppModelUserID(const AppModelUserID: WideString): HRESULT;
var
   ps: IPropertyStore;
   value: OleVariant;
const
   PKEY_AppUserModel_ID: TPropertyKey = ( fmtid: '{9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}'; pid: 5);
begin
   Result := SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(Self.Handle, IPropertyStore, {out}ps);
   if Failed(Result) then Exit;

   if (ps = nil) then
   begin
      Result := E_FAIL;
      Exit;
   end;

   if AppModelUserID <> '' then
   begin
      value := AppModelUserID;
      Result := ps.SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, PROPVARIANT(value));
   end
   else
   begin
      {
         A window's properties must be removed before the window is closed.
         If this is not done, the resources used by those properties are not returned to the system.
         A property is removed by setting it to the PROPVARIANT type VT_EMPTY.
      }
      value := Unassigned; //the VT_EMPTY type
      Result := ps.SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, PROPVARIANT(value));
   end;
end;
```

### Bonus Reading

- [What if my application is really two applications bundled into a single file, and I want them collected into two groups on the taskbar in Windows 7?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/17/10340743.aspx)
- [How do I prevent users from pinning my program to the taskbar?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/01/10170113.aspx)
- [SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.